# Using skew to make a parallelogram in react-native

Tags: react-native

I've been messing around with react-native and I was trying to create a parallelogram. I've tried using skewY but it just seems to behave almost the same as a normal rotate.

Here's my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: '#F5F1FF', flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onForward} style={[styles.parallelogram, {backgroundColor: '#443067'}]}>
          <Text style={{color: '#F5F1FF', fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '400' }}>Alpha</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onForward} style={[styles.parallelogram, {backgroundColor: '#6A42A8'}]}>
          <Text style={{color: '#F5F1FF', fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '400' }}>Bravo</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onForward} style={[styles.parallelogram, {backgroundColor: '#B485FF'}]}>
          <Text style={{color: '#F5F1FF', fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '400' }}>Charlie</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parallelogram: {
    width: 200, 
    height: 135, 
    transform:[{skewY:'-30deg'}], 
    justifyContent:'center', 
    alignItems:'center',
  },
});
```

And here's a screenshot of what it ends up looking like.

[image: And here's a screenshot of what it ends up looking like.]

Comment: Hey @Reverate did you find a way for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `skewX` to get a parallelogram:

```
<View style={{ transform: [{ skewX: '20deg' }] }}></View>
```

Unfortunately it's `iOS` only at the moment

Answer (score 0):

According to http://browniefed.com/blog/the-shapes-of-react-native/ you cannot do skew but have to create the start and end triangles yourself!

In your case you can also use a trapezoid that is to wide and then reposition it to the left so it partially hides the left of the trapezoid, making it look like a parallelogram...